# pregunta en allpromise

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola buenas tardes tengo una duda, poseo una función que se llama "ListarUsuariosMaxDate", me devuelve una respuesta y con esa ejecuto otra promesa que se llama un "actualizarProceso", mi pregunta es la siguiente, si en la función "actualizarProceso"  le falla uno de los "findOneAndUpdate", falla todo el proceso en esa promesa? o puede que actualiza uno y otro no? disculpen estoy comenzando acá el código:

```
 function actualizarProceso(lista) {

        const arregloDePromesas = []


        lista.forEach((elemento) => {


            var promesa = User.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": elemento.user },
                { $set: { "pasarela": elemento.previo.pasarela, "fecha_fin": elemento.previo.fecha_fin, "dispositivos": elemento.previo.dispositivos, "estado_token": elemento.previo.estado_token } }
            ).exec()

            arregloDePromesas.push(promesa)

            var asigSos = UserSos.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": elemento._id },
                { $set: { "flagSos": true } }
            ).exec()
            arregloDePromesas.push(asigSos)

        })

        return Promise.all(arregloDePromesas);
    }


    ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response => {
        return ListaconCondicionProceso(response);
    }).then(response => {
        return filtrarPagos.then(responseData => {
      
        return actualizarProceso(response);
           
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e); 
          }).then(response=>{
            return res.status(200).json(response)
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e); 
          })
    
    })
}
```

de antemano gracias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la documentación [oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all).

> Promise.all  se cumple cuando todas las promesas del iterable dado se han cumplido, o es rechazada si alguna promesa no se cumple...

También:

> Si alguna de las promesas pasadas en el argumento iterable falla, la promesa all es rechazada inmediatamente con el valor de la promesa que fué rechazada, descartando todas las demás promesas hayan sido o no cumplidas. Si se pasa un array vacío a all , la promesa se cumple inmediatamente.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu pregunta está orientada a saber si al fallar una operación de escritura en Base de Datos usando un iterable en [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all), todas fallan, entonces la respuesta es **NO**.

Hagamos un ejercicio muy básico:

```js
let entrada = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let baseDeDatos = [];
Promise.all(entrada.map(element => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // simulamos un proceso asíncrono
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(element !== 4 && baseDeDatos.push(element*2)) {
        return res('Aprobado');
      }
      rej('Rechazado');
    }, 500);
  });
}))
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log('baseDeDatos: ', baseDeDatos);
}).
catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log('baseDeDatos: ', baseDeDatos);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En cada iteración, se escribe un valor en la lista (base de datos), excepto cuando el valor es 4. Esto es exactamente lo que ocurrirá con la escritura en la base de datos, se realizará dicha escritura y si alguna falla, las que quedaron escritas seguirán escritas.

Por lo tanto, no puedes asegurar que si la Promesa es rechazada los datos no han sido almacenados en la base de datos, ya que puede suceder que todos excepto 1 fue escrito o que ninguno haya sido escrito, o que los primeros `n` fueron escritos.

La solución al posible problema que veo que planteas en tu duda es usar [*transacciones*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/), sin embargo las mismas nos están disponibles hasta la versión 4.0 de MongoDB en servidores de réplica o a partir de la versión 4.2 en servidores de réplica y de clúster fragmentado (Mongo Atlas, por ejemplo). Si ese fuera el caso, sería sencillo escribir tu código para realizar el proceso de transacciones (y puedes usar Mongoose siempre que dispongas de la versión 5.2.0 o superior).

Pero si no tuvieras la posibilidad de usar transacciones, entonces la solución al problema sería crear tu propia lógica de transacciones, lo cual dependerá de la complejidad de las operaciones y la forma en que realizas los procesos de actualización de datos.